# Change type from ObjectId to string

Tags: mongodb

I have some corrupted documents in my mongodb so I want to write a repair script which should fix it. However, it doesn't work.

```
db.History.find({_id:{ $type: "objectId" }}).forEach( function (x) {   
  x._id = x._id.valueOf(); // convert field to string
  db.History.replaceOne({BId:x.BId, "Version.Version": x.Version.Version}, x);
});
```

But I get an exception

> Failed to execute script.
>
> Error: WriteError: The _id field cannot be changed from {_id:
>   ObjectId('59cd189e6e5c9e1ca90b072c')} to {_id:
>   "59cd189e6e5c9e1ca90b072c"}.

How can it be done? I now have an exception in my app layer because it cannot deserialize ObjectId field as string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `_id` value of a document is immutable, so you need to create a new copy of the document with the corrected `_id` value, and then delete the original document.

So something like:

```
db.History.find({_id:{ $type: "objectId" }}).forEach( function (x) {
  var oldId = x._id;
  x._id = x._id.valueOf(); // convert field to string
  db.History.insert(x);
  db.History.remove({_id: oldId});
});
```

Comment: I'm only removing document before inserting because otherwise it violates some unique keys. I suppose it's better to exchange your last two lines.