# cannot convert ObjectId to String in MongoDb forEach function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, foreach, cursor, objectid

I'm trying to process data in mongodb between different collection  using cursor.forEach.

The tool is DataGrip `2021.3.1` and the MongoDB server version is `4.4.9`.

The statement is like below:

```js
db.reward.find({type: "Test"}).forEach(
function (p) {
    db.reward_order.find({rewardId: p._id.valueOf()}).forEach(
        function (order) {
            print(order.status)
        }
    );
}
);
```

I check each reward id in reward order collection and print the order status.

The problem is, the `p._id` is an ObjectId while the `rewardId` field in `reward_order` collection is a string, so I have to convert to String by invoking `p._id.valueOf()` by following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668537/6228210. but it does not work for me.

Error message:

> TypeError: invokeMember (valueOf) on org.bson.types.ObjectId@5d2a6048 failed due to: Unknown identifier: valueOf
> TypeError: invokeMember (valueOf) on org.bson.types.ObjectId@5d2a6048 failed due to: Unknown identifier: valueOf
> at user_script:46:67
> at _ex (user_script:42:25)
> at Cursor.forEach (all-standalone.js:155221: ...

**Update on Jun 24:**

I tried a few alternatives found from SO and some of them can achieve the effect and some not. Hope it helps anyone who are stuck with similar problem.

I'm quite confused why mongo syntax is so inconsistent with the official doc at [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), appreciate if anyone could help shed light on this. Thanks. I will also dig more later.

provided a as ObjectId, here is the test result in mongosh and DataGrip respectively:

**mongosh**

```
## This works well.
> a.toString()
00000001fbc548c26669b869
> typeof a.toString()
string

## This returns still an ObjectId, not String.
> a.valueOf()
ObjectId("00000001fbc548c26669b869")
> typeof a.valueOf()
object

## It just does not work, don't know why.
> a.str

> typeof a.str
undefined
```

**DataGrip**

none of above ways work in DataGrip. currently the only trick that works is concat the ObjectId with and empty string, like:

```
print(p._id + '');
```

Comment: I think DataGrip has a problem, in Navicat everything  work.

Comment: Yes, I just tried Navicat and it works well. I believe it's the different javascript engine in different mongodb client that lead to inconsistent behavior, but I have't found any official documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

try this. hope it may help you.

```js
db.reward.find({type: "Test"}).lean().forEach(
function (p) {
    db.reward_order.find({rewardId: p._id}).forEach(
        function (order) {
            print(order.status)
        }
    );
}
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried in both mongosh and DataGrip, it reported error `TypeError: :generatorexpr:20.lean is not a function`. is `lean()` only available in Mongoose?

Comment: sorry to hear that. I thought you were using mongoose.